# Xcode builds x86 code for ios application of debug version

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I know it is the right behavior but I am just curious about the flags that Xcode passes to clang, because I see only "arm*" architectures instead of "x86/x86_64" in the Xcode build settings even in debug mode.

Where is this x86 specifier in the build settings or clang command line? How can I see the final command line that Xcode passes to clang?

Answer (score 0):

The [Log Navigator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-log_navigator/articles/log_navigator-about.html) shows you all the arguments that is passed to clang compiler.  Since this is building for the iPhoneSimulator it passes i386.

[image: Example of Build Log]

Answer (score 0):

Xcode "does the right thing" in translating archs for iOS from device to sim.  armv6 and armv7 result in an i386 slice being created.  arm64 results in an x86_64 slice.  Similarly, the deployment target version is used with -mios-simulator-version-min=... instead of -mios-version-min=...